# Flexbox order when in different divs?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to change the `order` of some items using flexbox. I've got a problem however because one of the items I want to change the order of is in a new div, so it isn't a direct child of the same parent that the other items are.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="something">
    <img src=""></img>
    <p>PARAGRAHP</p>
  </div>
  <h1>TITLE</h1>
  <h4>SUBTITLE</h4>
</div>
```

I'm trying to move the paragraph below the title and subtitle, I made a codepen here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjYmZX

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`order`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-property) property controls the re-ordering of flex items in the same container.

In your mark-up, `.something` is a flex item, along with siblings `h1` and `h4`. The children of `.something` are in a different container and, hence, cannot be re-ordered with the parent and uncles.

If it's not absolutely necessary to have your image and paragraph in a different container, just put them in the main container. Then you can order everything however you like.

Here's an example:

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align:center;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  height: 300px;
  align-self: center;
}

p {
  order:3;
}

h1 {
  order:1;
}

h4 {
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Puffer_Fish_DSC01257.JPG/1280px-Puffer_Fish_DSC01257.JPG"></img>
  <p>ICONS HERE</p>
  <h1>TITLE</h1>
  <h4>SUBTITLE</h4>
</div>
```

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJVeVR)

Comment: Thing is I'm setting up a wordpress site, where the template is placing the img and paragraph in the same div. Which is why I can't just take it out of its div.

Comment: Then that div is a sibling to the `h1` and `h4`, and the `order` property won't work as you want. To have `order` control over the four objects, each would have to be a flex item in the same container.

Comment: I was afraid so. Was just hoping there was a workaround somehow that didn't involve me changing the themes file. Thanks for the response though :)

Comment: @StephanOlsen , rewrittem your template was the best thing to do , clean and coherent HTML makes styling easy ;) , workaround comes awfull, http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pgadxR example playing around with floats that nobody would want to use, it breaks if one title breaks into many lines of course.

Answer (score 1):

for this kind of reordering, display table properties should help :

```css
img {
  height: 300px;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}

.something {
  display: table-row;
}

p {
  display: table-footer-group;
}

h1 {
  display: table-caption
}

h4 {
  display: table-header-group;
}

* {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="something">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Puffer_Fish_DSC01257.JPG/1280px-Puffer_Fish_DSC01257.JPG" />
    <p> ICONS HERE </p>
  </div>
  <h1>TITLE</h1>
  <h4>SUBTITLE</h4>
</div>
```

but maybe, it would be wised to set things in html into the correct order :)

Comment: I'm setting up a site in wordpress so I can't just take the element out of its div, as the template I'm using puts the paragraph into the same div as the image. 
Your suggestion seems to place the title and subtitle above the image. I want it to be placed with image first, title, subtitle and then paragraph at the end.

Thanks for the response though.